# Reduce the time of 2 dimension join in C

Tags: c, join, 2d, sse, simd

Recently I wrote a program in C. During code execution, data calculation is bottleneck. As following:

The data structure is:
`typedef struct tuple_t{
     int oid;
    int min_x;
    int min_y;
    int max_x;
    int max_y;
}tuple_t`

the code is

```
for (i = 0; i < Qry->num_tuples; i++) {
tuple_t Qi = Qry->tuples[i];
for (j = 0; j < Obj->num_tuples; j++) {
 tuple_t Oj = Obj->tuples[j];
 int test_top_bit = (Oj.min_x - Qi.min_x) | (Qi.max_x - Oj.min_x)
     | (Oj.min_y - Qi.min_y) | (Qi.max_y - Oj.min_y);
     test_top_bit >= 0 ? matches++ : 0; 
  }
```

}
The code is uesd for testing whether a point is in a rectangle in 2 dimension.
The Qry->num_tuples and Obj->num_tuple is 5 million. I run the test, the time is 887 millionseconds. 
And I test the clasue

```
if(Oj.min_x == Qi.min_x)
    count++;
```

the time is only 3 millionseconds. So the major time is spent on the clause:

```
int test_top_bit = (Oj.min_x - Qi.min_x) | (Qi.max_x - Oj.min_x)
     | (Oj.min_y - Qi.min_y) | (Qi.max_y - Oj.min_y);
     test_top_bit >= 0 ? matches++ : 0;
```

I used another join algorithms, but the time is still very long.

Is there anyways to improve the performance of the testing?Could SSE of SIMD be using  ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this line I see a performance problem:

```
tuple_t Oj = Obj->tuples[j];
```

You copy this struct 25 trillion times for no reason except cleaner code.
Try using a pointer instead.
    tuple_t* pOj = &Obj->tuples[j];

You can also avoid branch:

matches += ( (Oj.min_x - Qi.min_x) | (Qi.max_x - Oj.min_x) |
             (Oj.min_y - Qi.min_y) | (Qi.max_y - Oj.min_y) ) >=0;

Comment: Hi egur, thanks for your kindly reply. I test your advice code and found that if I use the code matches += ( (Oj.min_x - Qi.min_x) | (Qi.max_x - Oj.min_x) | (Oj.min_y - Qi.min_y) | (Qi.max_y - Oj.min_y) ) >=0; It will return the wrong result. And using the code: tuple_t* pOj = &Obj->tuples[j]; the time is still long. For this problem I use SIMD SSE2 to resolve it and very efficient.